# how XML is used to generate layout in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

Recently i was looking into XML and came to know it is mostly used for data transfer and storage.
So how  it is used in android with views and what is the process to generate a view in android deep inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens behind the scenes is when an `XML` resource file is passed to an inflater to be inflated. The XML is first parsed using an `XmlPullParser`, each of the tag is mapped to a `object` of it's respective type, and each of the attributes are assigned as properties to these objects. Similar process is followed by `XAML` in the `.NET Framework`.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html). Basically XML element becomes an object and its attributes become object properties.

Answer (score 0):

before getting into xml .. just go through the concepts of html,css and javascript!! because in android all the xml elements are fetched through their id
 which is similar to javascript! and in android xml is used to set the layout of a activity and things related to it

Comment: i know how basic's work here and i how fetching a layout with id's is done.What question meant is how it works deep in android.